# How to implement insert, update, delete with a many-to-many relationship for tags?

Tags: update, insert, sqlite, delete, many-to-many

I am creating an application to manage some ebooks and I would like to have tagging functionality.
The best db design I have found is to be the many-to-many relationship. I know how to set up my tables but since I am inexperienced, I can't exactly figure out how an insert, update, delete would look like.

```
Ebook Table:
- id
- name

Tags Table:
- id
- name

TagsToEbooks
- ebook_id
- tag_id
```

I am working with C++ and Sqlite. Let's say I have a C++ function that takes an array of tags and I want to associate them with a certain ebook. How would I implement or write it? How should I use placeholders? Do I iterate over the array and run a SQL statement for each single tag?
Moreover, if I am deleting all tags associated with an ebook, they might remain in the tags table with no associations in the linking table(that has ebook_id and tag_id).

Please teach me how to cover these scenarios.

Some thoughts I had using pseudocode:

```
// When I want to insert a books tags
insert or select id if  it exists
then insert association


// When I want to update a books tags
delete associations of book
then do the insert function


// When I want to delete a books tags
DELETE FROM tasglink WHERE book_id in (SELECT id FROM ebooks WHERE name = :name)

//Create a trigger After delete on tagslink
DELETE FROM tags WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tagslink WHERE GROUP BY id)
```

Comment: Some of your questions you'll find the answers to by using [foreign keys](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html).

Comment: @J.D. In the association table, I used foreign keys for the book id and the tag id. One thing is, what if there are no more associations for a certain tag and it remains intact in the tags table? How do I approach this? Do I create a trigger that checks if that tag still has associations?

Comment: *Let's say I have a C++ function that takes an array of tags and I want to associate them with a certain ebook. How would I implement or write it?* 1st step - try to insert tags, one-by-one, ignoring duplication errors. After this all tags in array are present in a table. 2nd step - insert ebook (check for dup too). 3rd step - insert (ebook, tag) pairs into adjacency table. Of course, create needed unique constraints and foreign keys (with needed cascade actions - and you do not need in triggers).

Comment: @Akina So this works for inserts. What about deletes? My main concern is having a tag with no association in the adjacency table. I do not want that. How do I deal with that?

Comment: The purpose of the foreign keys (with cascade actions) is when you delete the parent associated entity, it will automatically delete the child as well, i.e. the `TagsToEbooks` entity. So it wouldn't be possible to have an orphaned record in `TagsToEbooks`, like you're concerned about.

Comment: @J.D. It is the reverse. I do not want to have a tag in the tags table left with no association in the TagsToEbooks table. Their cannot exist a tag with no association, the tag is useless without an association.

Comment: What's the point of a separate `Tags` table at all then? It sounds pretty ephemeral and completely driven by the `TagsToEbooks` table, making it somewhat redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation may be:

```sql
-- books table
CREATE TABLE Ebook (ebook_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                    name VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE);

-- tags table
CREATE TABLE Tags (tag_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                   name VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE);

-- adjacency table
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
CREATE TABLE TagsToEbooks (ebook_id INT,
                           tag_id INT,
                           PRIMARY KEY (ebook_id, tag_id),
                           FOREIGN KEY (ebook_id) REFERENCES Ebook (ebook_id) 
                               ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
                           FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES Tags (tag_id)
                               ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);

-- Trigger which will delete unused tags after book deletion
CREATE TRIGGER delete_unused_tags
AFTER DELETE ON Ebook
BEGIN
    DELETE 
    FROM Tags 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                       FROM TagsToEbooks
                       WHERE Tags.tag_id = TagsToEbooks.tag_id);
END;
```

[DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3240437678fe642477e75f07a30affb6)

Comment: Would you be so kind to explain the code further. I saw the demo and that is what I want but I want to make sure I understand the implementation. Thank you.

Comment: @mariofares Please ask specific questions. What exactly is unclear?